# Count Occurances of Int Values Returned From Large mysql Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Working on a mysql query which will return probably 5-7 million rows as result.  Most of the lines are being used elsewhere but the query is being processed in PHP line by line (mysqli_fetch_assoc()) using while() as to not make an excessive array.  The data in question returns an integer (0-30) calculated using:

```
$diff_time = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,0);
```

Require: A count of occurrences for each lines output (0-30), probably in the form of an array.  Ex. 27x #1's, 45x #2's, etc.  I don't care about making it look like that, the final output will be a csv...just need to know how to efficiently count occurrences in this scenario.

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` in the query.

Comment: Why not do it in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an associative array keyed by the `$diff_time` values.

```
$times = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // ...
    $diff_time = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,0);
    @$times[$diff_time]++; // @ to suppress notice about undefined index
    // ...
}
print_r($times);
```

Comment: I think you need `$times[$diff_time] = ($times[$diff_time] ?? 0) + 1;` otherwise it's undefined the first time

Comment: @billynoah It automatically defaults to `0`.

Comment: Yes but this will generate a notice, e.g.: `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5`

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `@` to suppress the notice

Comment: That works - On principal I'd prefer to write code that doesn't generate an error, rather than code that does and then suppressing it.  Most of all, I agree with your comment above that this should be done in sql.